# no errors and empty browser screen?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a very simple *.py file:

```
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       user = users.get_current_user()

       if user:
           self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
           self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
       else:
           self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                          debug=True)
```

when i run it locally and click on browse on the 'google app engine launcher' i get a blank screen in the browser, no error messages or anything.

This code in the same file is working though:

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

any idea why?
Thanks! Tom.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this code, apart from a missing import:

```
import webapp2
```

It runs and displays:

> Hello, test@example.com

You should also forget about using `Print` in app engine. It's not very useful. Send your output to the response  as you have done in the example code or use [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  (r'/(.*)', MainPage),
], debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

with an app.yaml like

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: True

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: test.application
```

Comment: any idea why i get this:

>Fatal error when loading application configuration:
>threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: oudejaar2012.py
>in "F:\GoogleAppEngine\oudejaar2012\app.yaml", line 10, column 3

when I copy your code as above? Your code is only working when i put threadsafe on false.

Comment: Id guess u put "test.py" as script into your app.yaml, not "test.application" (yes, the ".application"-suffix is correct)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a problem connecting with the Google login URL, try to put a response.write in case of the user doesn't exist.

```
if user:
    ...
else:
    self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
```